# IntelliJ IDEA 13 Scala Plugin & Eclipse Kepler Compilation Error

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, intellij-idea, guava

[image: IntelliJ IDEA]
[image: Eclipse]

**Code :**

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object MainJ extends App {
   val fantasyGeneres = Array("Space Opera", "Horror", "Magic realism", "Religion")
   val joined = Joiner.on(',').join(fantasyGeneres.toIterable.asJava)
println(joined)
}
```

**IntelliJ IDEA Error :**

```
scala: error while loading Joiner, class file 'C:\guava-    15.0.jar(com/google/common/base/Joiner.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 9 at byte 10)
```

**Scala Plugin Version :**

```
Scala -> 0.26.318
Version: 0.26.318
Date: 2013-12-04 10:46
Since: 133.124
Until: 134.0
Size: 25346.32 Kb
```

**Eclipse Error :**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error while loading Joiner, class file 'C:\guava-15.0.jar(com/google/common/base/Joiner.class)' is broken (class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 9 at byte 10) Scala       Unknown Scala Problem
```

please see above images, I wrote a program with Guava library and scala language

**WHEN** I use **Eclipse IDE with Scala Plugin & IntelliJ IDEA with Scala Plugin** above error shows and I cant compile it

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You're using JDK8 which isn't even officially out, are you sure it's not an incompatibility issue with that+Scala?

Comment: Make sure you have upgraded the scala plug-in. The scala plug-in is not bundled with IDEA and therefore must be manually updated after upgrading from IDEA 12 to 13.

Comment: I Updated my post please see new info

Comment: Do other Guava classes work properly? And what happens if you include Apache Commons instead of Guava and use its StringJoiner instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a fault of IDE. In fact it is how Scala compiler works. Unlike Java compiler, Scala compiler needs all the annotations for all libraries directly used by your code. Guava depends on JSR-305 annotations, so you must include corresponding JAR into your build.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007994/why-do-i-need-jsr305-to-use-guava-in-scala/10013226#10013226) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild) for more information. This is Maven dependency descriptor, copied from [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.findbugs%7Cjsr305%7C2.0.2%7Cjar):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```