# JAR file library included using Gradle fileTree isn’t being seen by Java code

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, dependencies, gradle

I created a new Java project in IntelliJ IDEA using its Gradle project template, and I am trying to set up a library so that my project can use it. I saved the library JAR file to `./libs/frink-2014-02-17.jar` in the project. In the `dependencies` section of my `build.gradle`, I wrote `runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`. But my Java code cannot see that library.  When I try to build the project, the compiler complains that `import frink.parser.Frink;` references a package that does not exist.

How can I fix my build errors, so that I can use the Frink library in my Java project?

### Details

The library is [Frink](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/). Frink is [not in the Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|frink), so I [downloaded its JAR file](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/#DownloadingFrink), renamed it so it has the version in the filename (following [the recommendation of the Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub%3aversioning_the_jar_name)), and put it in a `libs` folder at the root of the project. Then I copied the following line of code from [Gradle User Guide: File dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub%3afile_dependencies) to try to include all JAR files in that `libs` directory I created:

```java
runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

But when I “Make Project”, or run `./gradlew build`, I get these errors:

```
/…/frink-soulver/src/main/java/Main.java:1: package frink.parser does not exist
import frink.parser.Frink;
                   ^     
/…/frink-soulver/src/main/java/Main.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Frink    
location: class Main     
        Frink interp = new Frink();
        ^                
/…/frink-soulver/src/main/java/Main.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Frink    
location: class Main     
        Frink interp = new Frink();
                           ^
/…/frink-soulver/src/main/java/Main.java:11: package frink.errors does not exist
        } catch (frink.errors.FrinkEvaluationException fee) {
                             ^
4 errors                 
:compileJava FAILED
```

My IDE highlights the same errors when I open and view `Main.java`, before I compile it.

My code in `Main.java`, including the `import`, is just [the Frink sample code](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/#EmbeddingFrink). And the [Frink online JavaDocs](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/integrate/) indicate that there indeed should be a `frink.parser` package in that JAR file. So it’s not that I’m asking for a package that doesn’t exist.

I have tried changing `runtime` to `compile` in `build.gradle`, but that didn’t make a difference.

When I open “Project Structure…” in IDEA and go to the Libraries section, the Frink JAR file is missing from that list. The list contains “Gradle: guava-12.0”, “Gradle: hamcrest-core-1.3”, “Gradle: jsr305-2.0.3”, and “Gradle: junit-4.11”. I don’t want to just click the + button to add a library using IDEA, because I think it would be confusing to have libraries included in two separate ways.

I’ve [searched for “Gradle fileTree”](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gradle+fileTree), but it looks like I’m using `fileTree` the same way as in those results.

I’m new to Gradle, IDEA, and setting up Java projects from scratch. So if any of my project setup seems weird or nonstandard, I am open to corrections. For example, if there’s a better way to include Frink than copying its JAR file into a folder in my project, I can do that.

### Detailed project contents

My full `build.gradle`:

```java
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    /* commenting this out for the question because the error still happens without this
    // http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild
    runtime group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '12.0'
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007994/why-do-i-need-jsr305-to-use-guava-in-scala/10013226#10013226
    // I'll include this dependency in case I decide I want to use these annotations
    compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '2.0.3'
    */

    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

My project file tree, as generated by `tree`:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── main
│   └── dependency-cache
├── build.gradle
├── frink-soulver.iml
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── libs
│   └── frink-2014-02-17.jar
├── out
│   ├── production
│   │   └── frink-soulver
│   └── test
│       └── frink-soulver
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── Main.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        └── resources
```

My full `Main.java`:

```java
import frink.parser.Frink;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frink interp = new Frink();
        interp.setRestrictiveSecurity(true);

        try {
            String results = interp.parseString("2+2");
            System.out.println(results);
        } catch (frink.errors.FrinkEvaluationException fee) {
            // Do whatever you want with the exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified it as a dependency for `runtime`, but you need it when you `compile`...

Comment: That’s not it. I tried changing `runtime` to `compile` inside `build.gradle`, restarting the IDE, and rebuilding, but I still get the same four build errors.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: That really should be it.  Please try `./gradlew clean build` from the command line.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Under what circumstances should I `./gradlew clean`? Every time I add a new dependency?

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: In general, no.  But given you were seeing some weird behaviour, it seemed sensible to ensure you were starting from a clean slate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your dependency rule from the `runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')` to the `compile files('libs/MyLibrary.jar')`. This works for me.

I have created [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206495) on Android bug tracker, please feel free to comment it.